# How to print a matrix using xtable?

Tags: r, tabular, xtable

I have a data set with 255 variables.

I load my dataset using

```
>agep=read.csv("ncsucurrent.csv")
>attach(agep)
```

From the dataset I just want to tabulate a subset of 4 variables. So I select the subset using

```
>enroll=agep[,16:19]


id  Q1_Item1  Q1_Item2  Q1_Item3  Q1_Item4
 1         4         4         4         2
 2         1         2         3         4
 3         3         4         4         4
 4         3         3         3         3
 5         2         1         1         1
```

The variables in the subset are in numeric form. I want them as factors, so I use:

```
enroll<- lapply(enroll, factor, levels=1:4, labels=c("Not at all", "To a small extent", "To some extent", "To a great extent") ) t( sapply(enroll, table) )
```

This produces a matrix displaying the number of responses per variable under each category (i.e., "not at all"...."to a great extent")

```
Not at all  To a small extent  To some extent  To a great extent 
Item1          1                  1               2                  1
Item2          1                  1               1                  2
Item3          1                  0               2                  2
Item4          1                  1               1                  2
```

Now I want to create a nice table using xtable. I use

```
>require(xtable)
>library(xtable)
>enroll=as.data.frame(enroll)
>enroll=xtable(enroll)
>print(enroll)
```

However, what it returns the original subset with labels

```
% latex table generated in R 2.15.0 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Wed Jul 11 00:27:10 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & Q1_item1 & Q1_item2 & Q1_item3 & Q1_item4  \\ 
  \hline
1 & To a great extent & To a great extent& To a great extent & To a small extent \\ 
2 & Not at all & To a small extent  & To some extent & To a great extent\\ 
3 & To some extent & To a great extent & To a great extent & To a great extent\\ 
4 & To some extent & To some extent & To some extent & To some extent \\ 
5 & To a small extent& Not at all& Not at all& Not at all\\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

What is the right way to subset the data and print the matrix (second from top) using xtable?

Comment: `xtable(t(sapply(enroll, table)))`?